# Float second div to right only when its fits next to the first

Tags: css, css-float

I have the following (simplified) html & css:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">Some text for div 1</div>
  <div class="two">Some text for div 2</div>
</div>

<style>
  .two {float: right}
</style>
```

When both elements fit together in their container, I want it to look like;

```
Some text for div 1                                                     Some text for div 2
```

However when they do not fit next to each other I want the second div's float to be removed, like;

```
Some text for div 1
Some text for div 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: try this
.1 {float: left}
.2 {float: left;text-align:right;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexbox can do that;

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.skinny {
  width: 60%;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 250px
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent skinny">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not `1 0 250px` for both, Paulie?

Comment: Because I don't want the size to change...`Flex:1` would cause the divs to expand which floats wouldn't do.

Comment: + 1 for flexbox, some serious possibilities there. After reading up on it I ended up using .left { flex-grow: 1 } since that's ok for me. Thanks for the answer! Non supporting browsers just have a little less nice UI experience, but they're probably used to that.... :)

Answer (score 1):

my variant without flexbox and more cross-browser

```css
.container{
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
.container::after{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.class-1, .class-2{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="class-1">Some text for div 1</div>
  <div class="class-2">Some text for div 2</div>
</div>
```